# Swift - message sent to a deallocated object - in swift optimalization level fastest

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, nszombie

my bug appears only when I change optimalization level to fastest (in none works good). I reacreate `dateSource` of `collectionView` with new layout, new fetch request (with other sort on sections) on `NSFetchResultController`, and change cell. App crash on "`dequeuereusablecellwithreuseidentifier`" after second recreate `dataSource` (first use first cell and first use second cell works good on reuse first cell i get an error "message sent to a deallocated object"). I use instruments to look for nszombies in swift (screen shot added below).

In my code I don't use `NSNotificationCenter`.

[image: postimg.org/image/sd33adn67/]

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

try using a strong reference for your controller to make sure that nothing get prematurely garbage collected.

Comment: I try use a strong reference but unfortunately it had no effect